# How to use parameter variable from function through function body scope?

Tags: javascript

How to use parameter variable "**id**" from **"BubbleGum.prototype.ToolBar = function(id**)" through a function "**checkmousepos(e,id)**" body scope ?.

I've tried to use inline method *onClick* , traditional method *element.onClick = dosomething();* and W3C Standard and microsoft method *element.addEventListener* with same problem happening which is **variable id = undefined.**

Can someone please for the love of universe vibrations provide me with a concise and simplistic answer not some tricky hack semi-trash.

```
BubbleGum.prototype.ToolBar = function(id) {

var TB = document.getElementById(id);

TB.style.position = "relative";
TB.style.marginLeft = (RootFrame.style.marginLeft);
TB.style.marginTop = "-22.0em";
TB.style.left = "0em";
TB.style.top = 0;
TB.style.height = "2em";
TB.style.width = (RootFrame.style.width);
TB.style.color = "black";
TB.style.backgroundColor = "#6a071a";
TB.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "0.4em";
TB.style.borderTopRightRadius = "0.4em";
TB.style.textAlign = "center";

TB.onclick = checkmousepos(id);


function checkmousepos(e, id) {
    document.write(id);

    //var TB = document.getElementById(id);

    var mousex = e.pageX;
    var mousey = e.pageY;

    id.style.marginLeft = mousex + "px";


    //TB.addEventListener("mousemove",dick,false);
    //document.write("jello");
  };
};
```

Comment: Why is this a prototyped property, it seems like just your run of the mill DOM modifications ?

Comment: `checkmousepos(e,id)` expects 2nd argument to be `id`. But in your call you are passing one arg. So `id` will be undefined

Comment: " I'm programming a graphical user interface for my own personal uses and this has nothing to do with the question I asked. adeneo "


How do I give event to checkmousepos in the prototype scope ? Sandeep Nayak

Comment: It does because it's seems complicated, but really it's a basic mistake, you're calling the function, not referencing it, it should be `TB.onclick = checkmousepos;` and you can't magically pass an ID as an argument like that.

Comment: Um...  why not it's clearly visible and detectable somehow, just don't know where the value is from my point of view?. adeneo

Comment: A prototyped method is generally a method that you want to share across multiple instances of a class. There's nothing in the prototyped `ToolBar` method to suggest any such behaviour, it's just basic DOM traversal and adding a few styles, so one wonders why it's prototyped to begin with ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nbqemp81/1/

Comment: adeneo that does not do what I asked for urgh.. -___-

Samuel Edwin Ward it's clearly written in the title!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this** points to element that has `onclick` attached. Passing `this` you have access to that element in the elper method `checkmousepos`

`TB` already points to selected element – why you don't use it?

```js
function BubbleGum() {}

BubbleGum.prototype.ToolBar = function(id) {

    var TB = document.getElementById(id);
    
    TB.style.color = "green";
    TB.onclick = function(e) {
        checkmousepos(e, this)
    }
    
    
    function checkmousepos(e, id) {
        console.log('arg', arguments)
        var mousex = e.pageX;
        var mousey = e.pageY;
    
        id.style.marginLeft = mousex + "px";
    };
}
    
var s = new BubbleGum().ToolBar('toolbar');
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
    some content
</div>
```

Comment: Your a crazy genius where did you find this information , what source did you use ?  Krzysztof Safjanowski
Please provide a reliable source.

Comment: That artilce will be good for start: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/ than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick and little more knowladge from there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I still have one issue I wanna move the rootframe instead of the toolbar how would I go about that? HERE IS MY CODE = https://jsfiddle.net/7reojzf9/ Krzysztof Safjanowski

Comment: @DominicHughes How and where you are calling `RootFrame` method? Some HTML will be also helpfull

Comment: updated the fiddler oh.. through the body of the execute function.
https://jsfiddle.net/7reojzf9/2/

Krzysztof Safjanowski

Comment: @DominicHughes root container should not contain other elements?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the callback as onclick handler, while in your code you calling the `checkmousepose` function and assigning the return value which is undefined as nothing is returned.

So you have to return a function which will be assigned as a onclick handler like this

```
function checkmousepos(id) {
    return function(e){
        document.write(id);

        //var TB = document.getElementById(id);

        var mousex = e.pageX;
        var mousey = e.pageY;

        id.style.marginLeft = mousex + "px";


        //TB.addEventListener("mousemove",dick,false);
        //document.write("jello");
    }
};
```

Comment: This returns undefined and seems like that would make it more complicated then needed

Answer (score 0):

id is already in BubbleGum.prototype.ToolBar closure context, so it is availble checkmousepos function, just use it.